# About speaker label how can I display speaker labels in android

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

Please help me about this problem I almost 1 week solving this but i cannot please help me this is my log the result is the same in the demo 
this is my code in RecognizeOptions

```
 private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions(InputStream captureStream) {
        return new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                .timestamps(true)
                .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_MP3)
                .interimResults(true)
                .smartFormatting(true)
                .inactivityTimeout(2000)
                .speakerLabels(true)
                .audio(captureStream)
                .wordAlternativesThreshold((float) 0.01)
                .wordConfidence(true)
                .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
                .build();
    }
```

this is my code displaying the speaker and the word

private class MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate extends BaseRecognizeCallback {

```
   @Override
     public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
     System.out.println(speechResults);

     SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens recoTokens = new SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens();

      if(speechResults.getSpeakerLabels() !=null) {
        recoTokens.add(speechResults);
        String speaks = "Speaker " + speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().get(0).getSpeaker().toString();
        showMicText(speaks);
        System.out.println(speaks);
      }if(speechResults.getResults() != null &&  !speechResults.getResults().isEmpty()) {
             String text =  speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript();
             showMicText1(text);
      }

   }
```

About SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens recoTokens = new SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens(); this is the code I get this code in WatBot example in github

```
package com.example.ezminute.activities;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.RecognizeOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeakerLabelsResult;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechRecognitionResults;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechTimestamp;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.BaseRecognizeCallback;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class SpeakerLabelsDiarization {
    public static class RecoToken {
        private Double startTime;
        private Double endTime;
        private Long speaker;
        private String word;
        private Boolean spLabelIsFinal;


        /**
         * Instantiates a new reco token.
         *
         * @param speechTimestamp the speech timestamp
         */
        RecoToken(SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp) {
            startTime = speechTimestamp.getStartTime();
            endTime = speechTimestamp.getEndTime();
            word = speechTimestamp.getWord();
        }

        /**
         * Instantiates a new reco token.
         *
         * @param speakerLabel the speaker label
         */
        RecoToken(SpeakerLabelsResult speakerLabel) {
            startTime = Double.valueOf(speakerLabel.getFrom());
            endTime = Double.valueOf(speakerLabel.getTo());
            speaker = speakerLabel.getSpeaker();
        }

        /**
         * Update from.
         *
         * @param speechTimestamp the speech timestamp
         */
        public void updateFrom(SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp) {
            word = speechTimestamp.getWord();
        }

        /**
         * Update from.
         *
         * @param speakerLabel the speaker label
         */
        public void updateFrom(SpeakerLabelsResult speakerLabel) {
            speaker = speakerLabel.getSpeaker();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Class Utterance.
     */
    public static class Utterance {
        private Integer speaker;
        private String transcript;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new utterance.
         *
         * @param speaker    the speaker
         * @param transcript the transcript
         */
        public Utterance(final Integer speaker, final String transcript) {
            this.speaker = speaker;
            this.transcript = transcript;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Class RecoTokens.
     */
    public static class RecoTokens {

        private Map<Double, RecoToken> recoTokenMap;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new reco tokens.
         */
        public RecoTokens() {
            recoTokenMap = new LinkedHashMap<Double, RecoToken>();
        }

        /**
         * Adds the.
         *
         * @param speechResults the speech results
         */
        public void add(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
            if (speechResults.getResults() != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < speechResults.getResults().size(); i++) {
                    SpeechRecognitionResult transcript = speechResults.getResults().get(i);
                    if (transcript.isFinalResults()) {
                        SpeechRecognitionAlternative speechAlternative = transcript.getAlternatives().get(0);

                        for (int ts = 0; ts < speechAlternative.getTimestamps().size(); ts++) {
                            SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp = speechAlternative.getTimestamps().get(ts);
                            add(speechTimestamp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            if (speechResults.getSpeakerLabels() != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().size(); i++) {
                    add(speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().get(i));
                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Adds the.
         *
         * @param speechTimestamp the speech timestamp
         */
        public void add(SpeechTimestamp speechTimestamp) {
            RecoToken recoToken = recoTokenMap.get(speechTimestamp.getStartTime());
            if (recoToken == null) {
                recoToken = new RecoToken(speechTimestamp);
                recoTokenMap.put(speechTimestamp.getStartTime(), recoToken);
            } else {
                recoToken.updateFrom(speechTimestamp);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Adds the.
         *
         * @param speakerLabel the speaker label
         */
        public void add(SpeakerLabelsResult speakerLabel) {
            RecoToken recoToken = recoTokenMap.get(speakerLabel.getFrom());
            if (recoToken == null) {
                recoToken = new RecoToken(speakerLabel);
                recoTokenMap.put(Double.valueOf(speakerLabel.getFrom()), recoToken);
            } else {
                recoToken.updateFrom(speakerLabel);
            }

            if (speakerLabel.isFinalResults()) {
                markTokensBeforeAsFinal(speakerLabel.getFrom());
                report();
                cleanFinal();
            }
        }

        private void markTokensBeforeAsFinal(Float from) {
            Map<Double, RecoToken> recoTokenMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            for (RecoToken rt : recoTokenMap.values()) {
                if (rt.startTime <= from)
                {
                    rt.spLabelIsFinal = true;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Report.
         */
        public void report() {
            List<Utterance> uttterances = new ArrayList<Utterance>();
            Utterance currentUtterance = new Utterance(0, "");

            for (RecoToken rt : recoTokenMap.values()) {
                if (currentUtterance.speaker != Math.toIntExact(rt.speaker)) {
                    uttterances.add(currentUtterance);
                    currentUtterance = new Utterance(Math.toIntExact(rt.speaker), "");
                }
                currentUtterance.transcript = String.format("%s%s ", currentUtterance.transcript, rt.word);
            }
            uttterances.add(currentUtterance);

            String result = GsonSingleton.getGson().toJson(uttterances);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        private void cleanFinal() {
            Set<Map.Entry<Double, RecoToken>> set = recoTokenMap.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<Double, RecoToken> e : set) {
                if (e.getValue().spLabelIsFinal) {
                    recoTokenMap.remove(e.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private static CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
}
```

this is my result

```
{
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:   "speaker_labels": [
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     {
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "confidence": 0.605,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "final": false,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "from": 2.43,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "speaker": 0,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "to": 2.93
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     },
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     {
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "confidence": 0.667,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "final": false,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.335 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "from": 3.3,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "speaker": 1,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "to": 3.82
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     },
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     {
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "confidence": 0.579,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "final": false,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "from": 4.15,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "speaker": 0,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "to": 4.69
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     }
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:   ]
2019-03-03 23:21:58.336 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out: }
2019-03-03 23:21:58.340 4354-4354/? D/io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 137002 5177089 w 48914 1018780 d 7995 317604 f 12673 12674 iot 105310 98590 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 3948.151
2019-03-03 23:21:58.345 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out: {
2019-03-03 23:21:58.345 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:   "speaker_labels": [
2019-03-03 23:21:58.345 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     {
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "confidence": 0.579,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "final": true,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "from": 4.15,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "speaker": 0,
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:       "to": 4.69
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:     }
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out:   ]
2019-03-03 23:21:58.346 27985-28793/com.example.ezminute I/System.out: }
```

this is the result in the demo

```
{
 "speaker_labels": [
  {
   "from": 2.43,
   "to": 2.93,
   "speaker": 0,
   "confidence": 0.605,
   "final": false
  },
  {
   "from": 3.3,
   "to": 3.82,
   "speaker": 1,
   "confidence": 0.667,
   "final": false
  },
  {
   "from": 4.15,
   "to": 4.69,
   "speaker": 0,
   "confidence": 0.579,
   "final": false
  }
 ]
}
{
 "speaker_labels": [
  {
   "from": 4.15,
   "to": 4.69,
   "speaker": 0,
   "confidence": 0.579,
   "final": true
  }
 ]
}
```

this is my output

```
Speaker0: hello hi hello
```

this is the output in the demo

```
Speaker 0:
    Hello. 
Speaker 1:
    Hi. 
Speaker 0:
    Hello.
```

please help me please I'm Begging all of you please help me please :( :( :(  I don't know what to do please I do my best but it is not enough I need all help please help me :( :( :(

Comment: please help me about this please

Answer (score 1):

With such a small audio track I am assuming that `onTranscription` is being invoked only once.

I think your intention is to make use of SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens to determine who says what and when, but you are not using it. All you are doing is instantiating an instance

```java
SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens recoTokens = new SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens();
```

and adding in the STT response

```java
recoTokens.add(speechResults);
```

but then `onTranscription` ends and `recoTokens` goes out of scope and disappears. Making the whole exercise pointless.

Your output is from

```java
String speaks = "Speaker " + speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().get(0).getSpeaker().toString();
```

Which is directly from the response you get from the STT service. The `get(0)` will be getting and allowing you to print the 0th (1st) element in the array. As you don't have an iteration, that is all you will be printing.

If you want to see all the speaker labels them you will need a for loop to go though all the speaker labels in the response.

The transcript that you output is the full transcript, and is not broken down by speaker labels, or time.

```java
String text = speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript();
```

I think you would like to be making use of `recoTokens` that you have set up, which on brief inspection would make use of

```java
recoTokens.uttterances()
```

Comment: recoTokens.utterances(speechResults)?? is this correct or recoTokens.utterances() only??

Comment: how do I put recoTokens.utterances sir??

Comment: please help me sir how to do it I do all my best but not enough please sir

Comment: and about broken down speaker labels or time how to do it sir please help me i tried looping the speaker seems the transcript is not in the proper speaker

Comment: Your questions are too broad and suggest that you don't really understand the code that you are reading. You may be better off spending some time honing your coding skills until you can actually read the `SpeakerLabelsDiarization` code and understand it. Until you can do that, what you are really asking for is sample code that makes use of `SpeakerLabelsDiarization`.

Comment: i understand the code actually but may problem sir is about displaying it i don't know how to separate the transcript by speaker please help me

Comment: sir please help me :(

Comment: until now this is my problem :(

Comment: `speechResults.getSpeakerLabels()` is an array, hence `speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().get(0)` gets only the first label. You need to iterate over the array to get all the labels.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().size(); j++) {

                   String speaks = "Speaker " + speechResults.getSpeakerLabels().get(j).getSpeaker().toString();
                   showMicText(speaks);
               }

Comment: i tried that but the speaker well definitely bring all down the speaker by word what i am trying to achieve is speaker with transcript just like the demo so accurate i tried all the method just like you said by using timestamps but is not working please help me sir i'm begging you :(

Comment: Which is what `SpeakerLabelsDiarization` does. It is elegant code, and not too difficult to read. 1. Instantiate an instance `SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens recoTokens = new SpeakerLabelsDiarization.RecoTokens();`  2. Parse the results `recoTokens.add(speechResults);` 3. Output the response. `recoTokens.report();`

Comment: i tried that but in my case i display it with transcript sir speaker with transcript and display in listview

Comment: "speaker": 0,
        "transcript": "null null null null null "
      }

Comment: sir please help me i'm begging you

Comment: If that didn't work, then as your issue is either in `SpeakerLabelsDiarization` or how you use it, then I think you need to contact whoever wrote it for advice on how it works and how to use it.

Comment: sir please help me I tried to contact but no reply :( please sir